# How to escape a set of characters in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, escaping

So I have a variable say "$x". I have to escape a set of special characters if they show up in this string. The characters I want to escape are:

`+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \`

I am not very good with regex, but I think that is how I should do it, yeah?

I can escape them like `str_replace("+","\+",$x);` for each special character, but I am not sure that is how it should be done. Any pointers anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php). It puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax. This is useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some text and the string may contain special regex characters.

Comment: Or if you want $chars = "+-&&||!(){}[]^"~*?:\\";

`code $yourRegEx = "expression here";
for($i=0; $i< strlen($chars); $i++){
  $yourRegEx = str_replace($chars[$i], "\".$chars[$i], $yourRegEx);
}`

replacesall chars from $chars with the escaped chars in your regex.